# Collecting random year from Random Date

Tags: javascript, date

So I have generated a random date from two dates

```
var dateOfInterest =  function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date());
```

Now I need to collect the year of the random date generated with the code:

`var yearOfInterest = dateOfInterest.getFullYear();`

This does not work. I would appreciate the assistance. Thank you.

Comment: "This does not work" is not a problem description, the getFullYear function absolutely works. (1) what did you expect to get, (2) what did you get instead, (3) what did you already investigate based on that mismatch. (also note that `var` is a legacy keyword and best avoided in new code: use `let` for variables that you're going to reassign values to, or `const` for set-once-and-stay-that variables. Both of those create variables that follow normal block scoping rules, as opposed to the ancient `var` which is function scoped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function definition does not need the `var`, just assign the function itself, then call it to receive the return value.

I've placed the `getFullYear` in the function after creating a `new Date` and changed the function name to a more describing one: `getRandomYearBetweenDates`

```js
function getRandomYearBetweenDates(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime())).getFullYear();
}

const res = getRandomYearBetweenDates(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date());
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Then how is `randomDate()` returning a date?

Comment: Not sure what your asking. `new Date` creates an `Date`, on which you can call `getFullYear`

Comment: @0stone0. Thank you so much. It now works. All I had to do was add the ".getFullYear()" function to the randomDate function. I guess I have to change the name of the randomDate function name to randomYear. Thanks.

Comment: @0stone0 the function is called `randomDate`, so we can expect it to return a date. Instead, you rewrote it to return _just_ the year, so either also change the function name (because it's _not_ generating a date anymore now), or pull that getFullYear back out because it doesn't belong there. (e.g. make a second function `randomYear(start, end) { return randomDate(start, end).getFullYear(); }` or something)

Comment: Yea, name does not makes sense after adding the getFullYear. I've changed the name! Thanks for the feedback.